# why command not working properly when wildcard is detected

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, wildcards

segment of code from shell script

```
 fname=$(sed 's/(.*//' <<< $p | awk '{ print $NF }')  
 if [[ $fname == *['!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]* ]]
 then
   flag1=0
 fi
```

where $p is one line from a text file .

p value is         `>= (short)BigBlock * DISK_SIZE + Size)`

when above shell script is executed for p value , its gives garbage result 
for example this appear on terminal

```
>= (short)BigBlock  file1 file2 file3 DISK_SIZE + Size)
```

where file1 file2 file3 are files in the folder

my guess is * is treated as ls command

what could be the possible solution

Comment: Please don't use abstracted values for the content of $p, you can't figure out regex issue without a real literal example. Show a real line from the file.

Comment: @Lizardx The OP is showing the value of `$p`.

Comment: How do you know that? It's not at all clear from the example. If the string value is x, then how can $p >= x, that makes exactly no sense at all. I don't believe that's what the value is based on the example, but the person never responded, so I'm giving this a downvote as well. I believe that what the person is actually showing is the contents of a word problem assigned by the teacher, which isn't understood.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: You probably have `echo $p` somewhere in your code. You need to double-quote `$p`.

---

No, `*` is not treated as the `ls` command. It is, however, treated as a filename globbing pattern due to being used unquoted somewhere (not in code shown in the question)

You need to take care both when assigning and using the value of `p` and use appropriate quoting to protect the string.

Filename globbing patterns are not expanded in here-strings:

```
$ cat <<< *
*
```

So there is nothing wrong with the unquoted use of `$p` in the call to `sed`.  However, it is almost always better to explicitly quote variable expansions. See also the unquoted use of `$fname` in your test.  That should be double quoted for sure.

You say that the script outputs the text

```
>= (short)BigBlock  file1 file2 file3 DISK_SIZE + Size)
```

There is nothing that would provoke this string to be outputted in the script shown in the question. This is probably due to you doing

```
echo $p
```

somewhere else in the script.

Again, use double quotes around `$p`:

```
echo "$p"
```

This way, you stop the shell from performing file name globbing on its value (expanding `*`).

In general, use `echo` only for static strings, and use `printf` for variable data:

```
printf '$p is "%s"\n' "$p"
```

Related to that last point: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 0):

To start with, while awaiting the real $p value string: make sure to quote the $p.

```
fname=$(sed 's/(.*//' <<< "$p" | awk '{ print $NF }')
```

Also note, `sed 's/(.*//'`is going to match to the end of the string.

```
f='(something) and more stuff';sed 's/(.*//' <<< "$f"
```

Results in of course, empty string.

```
f='(something)-and more stuff';sed 's/([^)]*)//' <<< "$f"
```

Results in: -and more stuff

Comment: Bash does not expand filename globbing patterns in here-strings.